# Property [specifications] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

**SOLVED:** Answer below.

I upgraded my Laravel project from 5.3 to 5.4 and then 5.5.

Only thing that is broken at the moment is when I go to a product edit page I get error:

```
Property [specifications] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

Exception:

```
public function __get($key)
    {
        if (! in_array($key, static::$proxies)) {
            throw new Exception("Property [{$key}] does not exist on this collection instance.");
        }

        return new HigherOrderCollectionProxy($this, $key);
    }
```

Which is caused by this line in the blade template:

```
@if($categories->specifications->first())
```

`$categories` variable is passed to view from ProductController like this:

```
$categories = Category::with('specifications.attributes')->find($product->getCategoryId());
```

[image]

What has changed in 5.4/5.5 that could have broken this line of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason I had to add `->first()` to `$categories` before accessing specifications.

`$categories->first()->specifications->first()`

On the same view this `$product->categories->first()` works fine and is returned the same way as categories in controller, but doesn't require another `->first()`. No idea why.

Comment: "For some reason"... The reason is that `$categories` is a `Collection`, and doesn't have a `specifications` property or method. Calling `->first()` will return a single `Category` model, which _does_ have a `specifications` property (in this case a `Collection`) associated. This is a common issue everyone faces when using Laravel; be aware of what your `$thing` is when trying to access its properties.